# Joi Nested schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I am trying to create nested schema in joi and it is throwing error

[Error: Object schema cannot be a joi schema]

```
var nestedSchema = joi.object({
    b: joi.number()
});

var base = joi.object({
    a: joi.string(),
    nestedData:joi.object(nestedSchema)
});
```

How should i define nested schema in joi?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use [object.keys](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectkeysschema) API

```
var nestedSchema = joi.object().keys({
    b: joi.number()
});

var base = joi.object({
    a: joi.string(),
    nestedData: nestedSchema
});
```

Comment: Thank you ... but there is a typo. It should be joi.object().keys instead of joi.object.keys

Answer (score 44):

Although Francesco's answer works, there's no need to use `object.keys()`. The error the question creator was doing is to pass a schema as a parameter to `joi.object()`.

So, creating nested schemas is as simple as assigning a schema to a key belonging to another schema.

```
const schemaA = Joi.string()
const schemaB = Joi.object({ keyB1: schemaA, keyB2: Joi.number() })
const schemaC = Joi.object({
  keyC1: Joi.string(),
  keyC2: schemaB  
})

Joi.validate({ keyC1: 'joi', keyC2: { keyB1: 'rocks!', keyB2: 3 } }, schemaC)
```

Comment: Using this method how would you require `keyB1:`?

Comment: @MattWeber `const schemaB = Joi.object({ keyB1: schemaA.required() , keyB2: Joi.number() })`

Answer (score 4):

just a tip based on Francesco's accepted answer:

if you need "nestedData" to be required -> "nestedData: nestedSchema.required()" in "base" will not work, you need to set it directly on "nestedSchema" just like any other parameter

```
    var nestedSchema = joi.object().keys({
        b: joi.number()
    })
    .required();

    var base = joi.object({
        a: joi.string(),
        nestedData: nestedSchema
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

With Joi version `17.6.0` you can use the `valid` function as below

```
const schema = Joi.object({
   type: Joi.string().valid('android', 'ios').insensitive()
})
```

This will throw an error if the type property is not `android` or `ios`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const base = joi.object({
     a: joi.string(),
     nestedData: joi.object({b: joi.number()})
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 6 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.