# Joi validation for the given schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, joi

What will be the validation of the following schema using Joi validation?
How do we validate nested objects and arrays?

```
const user = {
        address: {
        contactName: 'Sunny',
        detailAddress: {
            line1: 'Sector: 2/A',
            line2: 'Q. No.: 3-018',
            line3: 'Near Shopping Centre'
        },
        pin: 827001,
        country: 'India'
    },
    cart: [
        {
            id: 'newId',
            count: 2
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `Object.keys()`
this link will help  you https://stackoverflow.com/a/36741711/2429434